# yii2 sluggable behavior

Tags: yii2, события, slug

Использую http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html

Пробую изменить slug перед сохранением в бд

```
    [
        'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
        'attribute' => 'name',
        // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
        // 'immutable' => true,
        // 'ensureUnique'=>true,
        'value' => function( $event ) {
            return 'test';
        },
    ],
```

В итоге в базу пишется slug сгенереный автоматом с name, а по идеи должно быть 'test'. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: закоментил 

`'attribute' => 'name',`

Теперь отрабатывает 

`'value' => function( $event ) {
            return 'тест';
        },`

Но теперь не транслитирует, т.е. написал тест, тест и вернуло, а не test :(

Comment: нашел ответ на свой вопрос здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073610/yii2-sluggablebehavior-attribute-or-value-property-must-be-specified-error